# Plot average of multiple line plots with different x values

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes that look similar to this:

```
x y     x    y
1 2     0.5  2
2 4     1.5  6
3 6     3    12
```

Where the x columns are my indices. I want to plot the average line plot for these multiple datasets. My idea was to concatenate the two dataframes so that I have a scatterplot and can do a best fit line, but Pandas is throwing an error `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. I've read other questions for this error message and have renamed my index names and column names to x_1 x_2 and y_1 and y_2 but it is still complaining, I believe because some of the x values are the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand completely how your dataframes look like, but you can concatenate two (or more) dataframes `df1,df2...` by doing:

```py
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df1,df2]),columns=['x','y'])
```

where my imports are

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Comment: My question was not completely understandable I'm afraid, but with your help I managed to concat the dataframes. Now, all I need is to somehow fit a curve through all my points, basically I need to interpolate x values I guess and then plot these interpolated values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a best fit line for all the points?  If so you can concat and use `lmplot`.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,4,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[.5,1.5,3], 'y':[2,6,12]})

out = pd.concat([df,df2])

sns.lmplot(data=out, x='x', y='y', ci=None);
```

[image]

Comment: That is almost what I want but instead, I want it to be a curve. My original data is not as linear as the example data in my post. Instead, I have 5 different 2-variate datasets (from 5 different experiment runs) and I would like to plot the average of those 5 runs.